# Matplotlib bar chart text couldnt be plotted correctly

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-analysis

[The result of the below code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvAMT.png)i tried ploting matplotlib bar graph but couldn't plot the text on correct position. Seems like it there is some problem with the x-axis i defined
The texts which needs to be top on respective bars gets squashed to side.
Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

```
# Define the data
high_values = [4, 1, 3, 1, 1, 0.0, 5, 2, 3, 13, 21, 61, 69, 77, 74, 49, 35, 25, 14, 9, 9, 20]
low_values = [29, 6, 6, 11, 15, 24, 45, 38, 47, 78, 68, 47, 46, 16, 11, 3, 2, 1, 2, 0.0, 0.0, 1]
close_values = [17, 4, 8, 8, 10, 7, 16, 22, 24, 44, 52, 53, 41, 51, 46, 31, 16, 18, 6, 4, 4, 14]

#Defining the percentage
high_percentages = [0.8, 0.2, 0.6, 0.2, 0.2, 0.0, 1.01, 0.4, 0.6, 2.62, 4.23, 12.27, 13.88, 15.49, 14.89, 9.86, 7.04, 5.03, 2.82, 1.81, 1.81, 4.02]
low_percentages = [5.84, 1.21, 1.21, 2.21, 3.02, 4.83, 9.05, 7.65, 9.46, 15.69, 13.68, 9.46, 9.26, 3.22, 2.21, 0.6, 0.4, 0.2, 0.4, 0.0, 0.0, 0.2]
close_percentages = [3.42, 0.8, 1.61, 1.61, 2.01, 1.41, 3.22, 4.43, 4.83, 8.85, 10.46, 10.66, 8.25, 10.26, 9.26, 6.24, 3.22, 3.62, 1.21, 0.8, 0.8, 2.82]

# Define the x-axis labels
labels = [-2.76, -2.5, -2.25, -2.0, -1.75, -1.5, -1.25, -1.0, -0.75, -0.5, -0.25, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2.0, 2.25, 2.5, 2.76]

# Define the width of the bars
width = 0.2

# Define the x-axis positions
x = range(len(labels))

# # figure size
plt.figure(figsize=(11,5))

# # Plot the bars
plt.bar([i - width for i in range(len(labels))], high_values, width,color="green")
plt.bar([i for i in range(len(labels))], low_values, width,color="red")
plt.bar([i + width for i in range(len(labels))], close_values, width,color="blue")

# # Add the x-axis labels
plt.xticks(x,labels)

plt.xlabel("Percentage")


# Add the y-axis label
plt.ylabel('Number Of Times')

# Add a title
plt.title(f'High, Low, and Close Values from {start_date} to {end_date}')

# Add a legend
plt.legend()

# Percentage text for day high
for x, y, p in zip(labels, high_values, high_percentages):
    plt.text(x, y, p,color="red")
    
# Percentage text for day low
for x, y, p in zip(labels, low_values, low_percentages):
    plt.text(x, y, p,color="green")

# Percentage text for day close
for x, y, p in zip(labels, close_values, close_percentages):
    plt.text(x, y, p,color="blue")
    
# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're not using the same X values between the `plt.bar()` and `plt.text()`

Using the same X values should work just as you want

```py
# [...]

# Plot the bars
x_high = [i - width for i in range(len(labels))]
x_low = [i for i in range(len(labels))]
x_close = [i + width for i in range(len(labels))]

plt.bar(x_high, high_values, width,color="green")
plt.bar(x_low, low_values, width,color="red")
plt.bar(x_close, close_values, width,color="blue")

# [...]

# Percentage text for day high  /!\ use x_high and not labels
for x, y, p in zip(x_high, high_values, high_percentages):
    plt.text(x, y, p,color="green")
    
#Percentage text for day low /!\ use x_low and not labels
for x, y, p in zip(x_low, low_values, low_percentages):
    plt.text(x, y, p,color="red")

# Percentage text for day close /!\ use x_close and not labels
for x, y, p in zip(x_close, close_values, close_percentages):
    plt.text(x, y, p,color="blue")
```

[image]

*Note that I took the liberty of changing the text color to match the bar color (green for "high" bar and text, red for "low" bar and text and blue for "close" bar and text)*